# Add up values in one column that fulfill condition in two other columns R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R, can't find an easy solution to my problem. I have a three-column table: *Location*, *Vegetation.type*, *Area*.

Each observation consists of a patch of vegetation. Each sampling site ("Location") is composed by numerous patches of vegetation, and within the same site, some patches contain the same vegetation type. I would like to add up the area of all the patches with equal *Vegetation.type* that occur within the same *Location*.

Therefore, the resulting data frame I expect would have for each *Location*, as many rows as *Vegetation.type*s there are. And the *Area* value would present the total extension of each *Vegetation.type* within each *Location*.

Comment: Can you add your dataset or an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using base R using the `aggregate()` function or using the `dplyr` library by first grouping by the `Location` and `Vegitation.type` then summing the `Area`.

Data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Location = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 15, replace = TRUE),
                 Vegitation.type = sample(c("grass", "tree", "flower"), 15, replace = TRUE),
                 Area = runif(15))
```

Base:

```
aggregate(Area ~ Location + Vegitation.type, df, sum)
```

Dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Location, Vegitation.type) %>% 
  summarize(total_Area = sum(Area))
```

Output:

```
#  Location Vegitation.type total_Area
#  <chr>    <chr>                <dbl>
#1 A        flower               1.55 
#2 A        grass                1.43 
#3 A        tree                 1.44 
#4 B        flower               0.320
#5 B        grass                0.828
#6 B        tree                 1.86
```